# How can I fix this error when chrome starts

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

After starting a chrome driver in java a SessionNotCreatedException is thrown by the application.
This is the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Development\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.get("https://google.com");
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-1', revision: '9c03156c2b'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-S9O6TAK', ip: '192.168.0.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome}}]
Capabilities {}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:252)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:86)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:41)
at de.antonbowe.fachecker.FAChecker.(FAChecker.java:57)
at de.antonbowe.fachecker.FAChecker.main(FAChecker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:153)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:153)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)
... 8 more

Process finished with exit code 1

I updated the chrome driver several times and tried other old projects. All dont work.

Answer (score 0):

When I was using `selenium-java` version `4.0.0-beta-3` alone, it worked fine. But after I added the following additional dependencies to my project (per https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java), I got the same errors.

```
google-api-client 1.23.0
google-oauth-client-jetty 1.23.0
google-api-services-gmail v1-rev83-1.23.0
```

I downgraded my `selenium-java` to version `3.141.59`. The error went away.